# Guarantee globalkey in super constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I have a StatefulWidget `InfoWidget` and I want to make sure it always has a key. I'm not able to provide a default value because it has to be constant. When I try to create a `GlobalKey` in the super constructor call I get a lot of `[ERROR] { exception: Null check operator used on a null value` errors in the app (everytime I want to access the currentContext `key.currentContext!...`)

```
InfoWidget(
  {required this.child,
  Key? key,
  : super(key: key ?? GlobalKey<InfoWidgetState>());
```

How is it possible for the key to be Null?

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `key.currentContext!`. I think the key works fine, but when you're calling it, the context hasn't been initiated yet

Comment: why don't you make it a required argument for that widget?

Comment: @dumazy, InfoWidget is used as a wrapper for other Widgets anywhere in the app. We just wrap like this: 
`return InfoWidget(
   ...
  child: this,
 )`

Comment: Yes, but where are you calling `key.currentContext!`?

Comment: @dumazy, Error is seen in flutter widgets like EditableText
`r.2521: RenderEditable get renderEditable => _editableKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderEditable;`

Comment: In general: is this the way to create a default value for a key?